# Preventing SQL injection while letting the user enter their own condition at the end of the query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

In my program I have a query that views *Contacts* information to the user. This table normally shows all the rows with no filter. I would like to add an option for the user to write their own condition at the end of the `SELECT` statement to view the information that they need. So if my main query is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS
```

The user can write the condition

```
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%Michael%'
```

In a textbox.

However, I am aware that this is not very safe and is prone to SQL Injection. But how can I prevent the user from entering malicious commands such as

```
WHERE 1=1; DROP TABLE Contacts
```

In the text box? For now I am using a check against some keywords e.g. if the filter contains DELETE, DROP, UPDATE, etc the query will not run. But I don't think this is a very safe solution.

Comment: Simply dont build your own SQL Queries this way. Use Parameters in your query. What database are you using?

Comment: Don't even attempt to prevent this from the c# code. It is impossible. All you need to do is parameterize your queries instead of directly executing the values being entered.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I am using parameters in all other queries. But here I would like the user to be able to write their own filters.

Comment: Either remove that feature or jail it by offering predefined possible conditions that they choose. That feature sounds so bad that I would completely scrap it. You expect people to know SQL and to know table structure? If true, why even bother with your program? Just give them an SQL GUI and an account that doesn't allow for dropping / deleting stuff.

Comment: Have the user select the filters in a dropdown with a value behind the scenes and then you can build up the SQL yourself in C#. Or, just apply a filter to the grid, since you're already returning all results...

Comment: @N.B. What you are saying makes complete sense. The annoying problem is that even if I make 500 prepared dropdowns for the filters I am sure the end user is going to complain with *"oh, what if I wanted all the users who are 25 years old and their name has Michael in it and were updated last September??"*. The dropdowns are good for adding only one condition. But if the user wants to filter based on more than one condition then they cannot get the result they want.

Comment: Sometimes you can't create a program that will satisfy everyone. You can use the same argument that you posted, but the user can say "Why would I use SQL for this, could you not add a visual aid for me to get the result I want". From experience, I know that people will use what they have at their disposal. If they require additional functionality, then you negotiate with them and bill it separately - that's what data analysts are doing. You can't cover all the scenarios that exist, so leave the option of people paying you to get them the data they need, but offer a sensible default.

Comment: How many columns are likely to be used as filters? If it's not very many then restricted the user to a predefined list sounds like the best way to go. You could build in an option to add multiple filters up to a maximum number. If there are lots of columns then perhaps build it around the most likely used columns. As it stands though this is a very bad idea.

Comment: Is the requirement just to restrict access to various tables and information for select only queries? If this is the case, consider giving access to the database, but create multiple schemas for various tables and views and restricting access for different users this way: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53509/setting-user-permissions-for-different-sql-server-schemas. Other than that, I agree with @N.B.s advice of jailing queries to valid values. Consider providing wildcard searchses for each field by default with an 'Exact match' checkbox to override. Also consider drop-down lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing a user to write "*their own condition at the end of a {SQL} query*", can create security holes in your application which will make it prone to things like a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If you still wish to proceed, here are a couple of things to consider:

- use regular expressions to limit input to its most basic form (e.g. phone number only allows 0-9 and hyphens)
- implement your protection mechanism at the lowest level (i.e. stored procedure)
- for dynamic queries in stored procedures... never pass in field names into the stored procedure
- Never run with more privileges than necessary.
- Users that log into an application with their own login should normally only have EXEC permissions on stored procedures.
- If you use dynamic SQL, it should be confined to reading operations so that users only need SELECT permissions.
- A web site that logs into a database should not have any elevated privileges, preferably only EXEC and (maybe) SELECT permissions.
- Never let the web site log in as administrator!
- Always used parameterized statements.
- Do a code review to check for the possibility of second-order attacks.
- Ensure that error messages give nothing away about the internal architecture of the application or the database.

Again... be very, VERY careful when you implement this!

## ADDITIONAL READING

- [Wikipedia: SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection)
- [SQL Injection Attacks and Some Tips on How to Prevent Them](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev)
- [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)
- [Top 10 tricks to exploit SQL server systems](http://hungryhackers.blogspot.com/2008/01/top-10-tricks-to-exploit-sql-server.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're right that this isn't safe. There is no safe way of doing exactly what you want. Arbitrary SQL filters means the user could equally use a `WHERE id IN (SELECT x FROM OPENROWSET(...))` selection, for instance, *still* allowing `DROP TABLE` executions.

What you *can* do is provide your own filter syntax, and using your own parser for that syntax, translate it to SQL. You can make sure only to allow features that are safe to use from SQL. Some ORMs may provide such a feature out of the box, otherwise you'll have to create something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider this feature a no-go as it is designed: Not only is the user expected to have knowledge about how the database works, he also needs to know both the correct syntax *and* the data model.

Try to mask this by providing predefined conditions, such as "where the user name contains..." or "the last name is".

On the C# side use parameterized queries to make sure the user provided input is sanitized.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to answer.  You want a search engine that will allow SQL conditions and this is the definition of SQL injection.

Here are a few workaround ideas :

- **Use a grid control** : You can display the query results inside a grid and allow the user to
  use the grid to filter the results.  This is easy to implement (you don't reinvent the wheel) and it is user friendly.  Moreover, some grids offer very powerful filtering options.  The only drawback I can see is that you'll often retrieve much more results from the database that what you actually needs.
- **Create your own filter syntax** : You can code your own filter syntax (hvd solution).  This is going to be a lot of work and if you miss something you might still end up with a security hole.
- **Code a condition build-up tool** : You can provide a condition build up tool.  This is very user friendly but in the end it may not be flexible enough.
- **Export to CSV** : You can offer a tool to export the query results to CSV for easy exploitation in *Excel* or *Calc*.  This would be very user friendly for experienced users with spreadsheet applications.